# How to display an image after a gif

Tags: java, android, gif

I am new to android. I implemented a GIF in my activity.

I found a way to make it loop only once. So far everything is fine but I would like to display the image of this gif at the end of the animation of this one, this time in image and not in gif. Basically I would like the gif to loop once and then become an image again

I implemented this on my build.gradle :

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.12.0'
```

After that I set up my imageView :

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fuse"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_4sdp"
    android:padding="@dimen/_8sdp"
    android:src="@drawable/fuseev4"
    tools:ignore="InvalidId" />
```

Now this is my java file to loop once:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = ActivityChatRoomBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
        imageView = binding.fuse;
        try {
            setListeners();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void setListeners() throws InterruptedException {
        binding.LayoutSend.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            try {
                Glide.with(this)
                        .asGif()
                        .load(R.drawable.fuseev4) //Your gif resource
                        .apply(RequestOptions.diskCacheStrategyOf(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE))
                        .listener(new RequestListener<GifDrawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onLoadFailed(@Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable GlideException e, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                return false;
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Object model, Target<GifDrawable> target, DataSource dataSource, boolean isFirstResource) {
                                resource.setLoopCount(1);
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .into(imageView);

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            afterListeners();
        });
    }
    public void afterListeners(){
        Glide.with(this)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(R.drawable.fuseev4)
                .into(imageView);
    }
```

I couldn't find a way to solve my problem.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: did you mean first show loading image(gif) then actual image should come

Comment: @MAYURSANCHETI Exactly, I want that às soon as he presses the button the animation of gif appears then an image

Answer (score 0):

1)as i read you are using bumptech.glide liabrary so try code like below,

```
private val image = "abc.png"



Glide.with(this).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder) .into(binding.imageView);  //here loading gif
```

comment if any query

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your onResourceReady() callback:

```
resource.registerAnimationCallback(new Animatable2Compat.AnimationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Drawable drawable) {
    super.onAnimationEnd(drawable);
    // your code here
}});
```